# Want to Set value in Session variable on change event of drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

I had js file within that js file i have on change event of drop down.
When I click on drop down i want to set default session value of x to that drop down value without having ajax call.

```
<select id="ddlPaymentType" name="PaymentType"><option value="DC">DRIVER COLLECT</option><option value="DB">DIRECT BILL</option><option value="PREPAID">PREPAID</option><option value="RC">ROOM CHARGE</option></select>
```

Want to set value to this value of session.

```
 SessionHelper.LoggedInUserInfo.DefaultPaymentType = defaultPayment;
```

Is that is any way that i can access value of session in js. If it is then how would i set particular value.

Comment: I would recommend saving this setting in the user database because i think this is a one time choise and i don't think the user want's to select it every time a new session was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <select>
                   <option value="<%= session.getAttribute("anything") %>"></option>

                 </select>
```

you can insert java code in HTML.